# Fake/Dummy/mock internet for spam apps

Tags: internet

There are a lot of apps which require internet to run whether be spam or good apps.

Is there any way to *make them feel there is internet connection* without actually running internet kind of fake/mock internet connection for such apps?

FYI, I am using ICS (Android 4.0.4)

Comment: The best way to prevent spammy apps from accessing the Internet is to uninstall them.

Comment: @Chahk: True but i also meant there are good apps and games too which require internet for marketing or ads and not their internal functionality to work with internet :)